# How to remove space between buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my app I see a lot of space between the colored buttons which i dont actually want, how can i remove them? I tried using `button.pack(pady=0)` for the buttons but it didnt have any effect

[image: Screenshot of my tkinter app showing the wide gap between buttons]

I've added my code here and tried to only put the relevant parts of the code

I added the canvas so i can add the scrollbar with it. And I used the buttons because i want to add a method that shows the page where the task can be edited/deleted.

```
class TodoFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        task_frame = Frame(self.canvas, height=self.winfo_height()-100)
        task_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='center', window=task_frame, width=self.winfo_width(), height=self.winfo_height()-100)

        priority_colors = ("#00CED1", "#00FA9A", "#FF6347", "#B0C4DE")  # colors for buttons
        # the db.fetch_incomplete_tasks() fetches tasks from mysql database
        # and returns a list of tuples containing title, description, priority and completion status of the task
        self.incomplete_tasks = sorted(db.fetch_incomplete_tasks(), key=lambda x: x[2])  # sorting list by priority
        if self.incomplete_tasks:
            incomplete_task_label = Label(task_frame, text="Incomplete Tasks", font=('calibri', 16))
            incomplete_task_label.pack(padx=(50, 0), anchor="center")
            
            for task in self.incomplete_tasks:
                title, description, priority, status = task
                task_btn = Button(task_frame, text=title, bg=priority_colors[priority-1], bd=0, width=25, wraplength=400, justify="left", pady=5)
                task_btn.pack(expand=True, padx=(50,0))
```

Comment: This code won't run for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @BryanOakley   such as?

Comment: @BryanOakley I think i understood why you said that so I edited my code to include the classes, really sorry for the confusion i mightve caused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I set the height of the canvas in this line
`self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='center', window=task_frame, width=self.winfo_width(), height=self.winfo_height()-100)`

which caused formation of extra space, and the space between the buttons was to fill up that gap